# What tool can I use to view the changes in an in-memory H2 database?

Tags: h2

I switched to using an in-memory H2 database for development. It works great, but I'm not able to see my changes as I make them.

This is their suggested list of tools: http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools

I tried DB Visualizer and SQL Developer, but I can't find the tables my software creates. Are there any gotcha's that I should be aware of when working with H2, or any suggestions on a nice tool for Linux.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about the [database URLs](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url)?

Comment: This helped a great deal! My problem was partly because I tried to access the in-memory database wrongly, but [this part of the doc](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generally just used their web interface, found at `http://localhost:8082` by default.

[Their quickstart guide](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html) covers making it available on Windows in great detail, but I recommend simply checking `http://localhost:8082` as a first step to see if it's already up and running.

Answer (score 2):

to be independent of the operating system used(Win,Linux(Ubuntu,..),Mac),Execute this command  :

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Console
```

It will open the browser : `http://localhost:8082`

[image]